# Quartz Composer iterator patch possible bug?

Tags: quartz-composer

On adding an iterator patch to an editor window all I see is a patch with 1 input (iterations). If I try to explode this patch to view the macro's sub-patches I get an empty editor window (same result if I double-click the patch). The patch inspector just shows the iterations index (preset to 10).

If a patch has no outputs and I cannot see the sub-patches how are we actually meant to use an iterator patch? I realise that a further patch called iterator variables helps with this but I still cannot see how I can make use of the iterator if it has no outputs.

I have looked online and there are a few tutorials on the subject of QC iterators but these are all using older versions of OS X  / Xcode - when things worked differently then and certainly look different to what I am seeing.

I have also seen odd behaviour with the QC viewer - it doesn't always update to show changes I have made in the editor, I have had to quit QC and restart to see updates at times. The error logs in the console don't reveal much in the way of error logging. 
Perhaps QC for Lion is broken?

I have tried deleting QC and downloading a fresh copy but still see the same result.
Any insight given much appreciated.

Perhaps I am totally missing the point about iterators, my thinking is that they allow the user to repeat effects from other patches by iterating over an index value but again, if the iterator has no output and I cannot seen inside it I just cannot see how to use iterators.

I am using a MacBook Pro on 10.7.3 Lion & Intel 2.3 GHz i5 processor.

Answer (score 3):

A simple Iterator tutorial:

1. Open an empty composition
2. Add a Clear patch
3. Add an Iterator patch
4. Descend into the Iterator patch by double clicking on the patch's body (not the title)
5. Add an Iterator Variables patch
6. Add a Line patch
7. Connect the Iterator Variables patch's "Current Position" output to the Line patch's "Start Position Y" input

This demonstrates:

- Everything inside the Iterator patch is executed multiple times (whatever the Iterator patch's "Iterations" input is set to)
- The Iterator Variables patch provides the context within the Iterator (i.e., where in the current iteration sequence you are)
- The Iterator patch doesn't need outputs in order to render stuff

It's also possible to publish outputs from patches within the Iterator (right-click on a patch, go to the Publish Outputs menu).  Due to limitations in QC's implementation, you can only publish outputs when there are no renderer (blue) patches inside the Iterator (or any other Macro).

When you publish an output from the Iterator, the outer patches see only the value from the last iteration.  To get around this, you can use a Queue patch inside the Iterator, to build up a structure, which you can then publish.

You should end up with something that looks like this: [image: Screenshot of QC Editor and Viewer]